# NTFS5 file system in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, ntfs

How can I get NTFS5 file system in XP? When I install XP to my PC it shows only format using FAT32 and format using NTFS. Which version of XP contains NTFS5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP uses NTFS 5.1, Windows 2000 used NTFS 5.0. Although if you want 5.0 for XP, you can probably pop in a Win2k disk and format the drive before installing XP. As with most software advancements, newer versions are usually better, so you will want to stick with what's provided.

More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Versions

Comment: Did you even read your source? It contradicts what you just said.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no such thing as “NTFS 5”. Windows 2000 uses NTFS 3.0, Windows XP and higher uses NTFS 3.1. They’re both backward and forward compatible in every regard except EFS (encryption).